# Keeping a div centered

Tags: html, css

I am working on my website where i have a div with some text that I want to have in the center of the screen, I have created this title dynamically that is, for different screen dimensions the margin on the div and font size of the text is changed. I thought this would be a good solution to creating a dynamic page, but it now seems that the transitions are a bit awkward. Is there another way to do this i.e. using percentages in the margin or something similar with font? I am doing all of this with only html and css
thanks

Comment: Please post your problem code (html/css/js) or make a jsfiddle or codepen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hard to say more specifically without you providing code examples. However, to center a div you should use the CSS property: `margin: 0 auto` where 0 is your arbitrary top/bottom margin. For this to work you will need to set an explicit width on the div.

```
/* in CSS */
.myDiv {
    width: 400px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Your question mentions that you want the size of the font and div to adjust with screen size. For this you will need to use Media Queries which are a way to adjust CSS depending on the detected window size.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries